# RStudio does not start with Mac OS Mavericks and R 3.1.2

Tags: macos, r

I am confronted with the problem that my RStudio does not start anymore. I got the newest version of RStudio 0.98.1091 and it all started after I installed the newest version of R. 
After some research and deleting all R versions on my Mac and reinstalling just the latest (R 3.1.2) it still has the same error. I am stuck with it. I can start R in Terminal and it is linked to /usr/bin/R. There is just one version in /Library/Applications/R.framework/...*/Version. So there is Current and R 3.1.2 but Current is a symlink to R 3.1.2. When I start Rstudio it is blank and just prints out, that there is a parsing error for a regular expression. I started with from terminal with the option --run-diagnostics and here is the whole error message:

```
Using R script: /usr/bin/R

Attempting to launch R session...
  RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R
  R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
  R_DOC_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc
  R_INCLUDE_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
  R_SHARE_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share
  PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/**/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
  HOME=/Users/hasan_gurcan

21 Dec 2014 12:01:11 [rsession-hasan_gurcan] ERROR Unexpected exception: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'r/local/**>>>HERE>>>/bin/?($|:'.; LOGGED FROM: int r::session::RReadConsole(const char *, CONSOLE_BUFFER_CHAR *, int, int) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/r/session/RSession.cpp:756
21 Dec 2014 12:01:11 [rsession-hasan_gurcan] ERROR R SUICIDE: Unexpected exception: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'r/local/**>>>HERE>>>/bin/?($|:'.; LOGGED FROM: void <anonymous namespace>::rSuicide(const std::string &) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2179
```

Comment: i asked the same question here. maybe it is helpful for other users. the problem was that i have /usr/local/**/bin in my path variable and it could not be solved by RStudio. SO here is the link [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202498107-RStudio-does-not-start-with-Mac-OS-Mavericks-and-R-3-1-2#answer-202407108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I had two different versions of R in my path. One was residing in `/Library/Frameworks/R.Framework` and one installed by Homebrew under `/usr/local`.

I solved it by deleting the one under `/Library/Frameworks` and keeping the (more up to date) Homebrew version.

Comment: This worked for me: `rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.Framework`

Answer (score 0):

Is your Mac running Yosemite (Mac OS version 10.10?). There are reported problems with R 3.1.2 not working with Yosemite.

Comment: this answer is not helpful. some links to the reported bugs would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but are you running the 32 bit or 64 bit version? I'm using 2.15.2 and the 32 bit version runs but the 64 bit version doesn't.

(I would have posted this as a comment to Randy's answer, but hooray for reputation-based comment blocks...)

Answer (score 0):

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202498107-RStudio-does-not-start-with-Mac-OS-Mavericks-and-R-3-1-2#answer-202407108

Maybe this helps, i was searching for something else and stumbled upon it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Due to links my break, you may quote the essential things in your answer.

Comment: this is the same question i linked in my comment